# Ubuntu software center remove configuration files

Tags: software-center, configuration, synaptic

`Synaptic` has options to remove the configuration files during uninstall, and I thought this was because the back-end `apt-get` has this as a parameter. How do I access this feature from the `Ubuntu Software Centre`, which replaces `Synaptic` as the default package manager software for Ubuntu?

I have a program which seems to have saved a configuration file wrong (LieroLibre) and now it just wont run at all. I tried reinstalling it to no avail.

[Edit] Ok, installed Synaptic and found its complete removal option doesn't actually remove `~/.FOLDERS` that the program creates. Deleted `./lierolibre` and it ran fine after that. Shouldn't those types of folders be considered configuration stuff?

Comment: Regarding your edit; while I would consider them config. files, they are not removed by Synaptic or by the `sudo apt-get purge` command while this is a pain it makes sense. If there are multiple users, removing the files in the home directory could cost a user files or personal settings that needed to be saved.  They could then move them to another computer.  On a more likely event; your program has been corrupted so you need to purge it and then reinstall, if it wiped your home folder it would also remove your custom settings or in Libreoffice a custom dictionary for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no conflict involved in installing both Synaptic and the Ubuntu Software Center. If you need to use a feature of Synaptic, it is possible to do so without it interfering in any way with the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: +1 the first things I do now with a new install it to install Synaptic.  the Software Center is good for searching for programs, it gives you great info without having to look for it but for advanced installs/uninstalls it doesn't come close to Synaptic.